# How to call a class from an activity

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android program that solve linear program problems. I'm using an external libraries for simplex solver from http://www.ssclab.org 
I already try the examples from the website and worked well in Eclipse.
Now I'm trying to implement the code in Android Studio java class.
However i don't know how to call this class from an Activity. 
How can i get the string "hasil" to MainActivity?

```
public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ArrayList< String > constraints = new ArrayList< String >();
        constraints.add("min:  3Y +2x2 +4x3 +7x4 +8X5 ");
        constraints.add("5Y +2x2 +3X4       >= 9");
        constraints.add("3Y + X2 +X3 +5X5   >= 12");
        constraints.add("6Y+3.0x2 +4X3 +5X4 <= 124");
        constraints.add(" y + 3x2 +3X4 +6X5 <= 854");

        LP lp = new LP(constraints);
        SolutionType solution_type=lp.resolve();

        if(solution_type==SolutionType.OPTIMUM) {
            Solution soluzione=lp.getSolution();
            for(Variable var:soluzione.getVariables()) {
            SscLogger.log("Variable name :"+var.getName() + " value :"+var.getValue());
            }
            hasil = "Value:"+soluzione.getOptimumValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one function in your activity like this and call that function whenever you want like at activity launch time or button click.

```
private void demoFunction() throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList< String > constraints = new ArrayList< String >();
        constraints.add("min:  3Y +2x2 +4x3 +7x4 +8X5 ");
        constraints.add("5Y +2x2 +3X4       >= 9");
        constraints.add("3Y + X2 +X3 +5X5   >= 12");
        constraints.add("6Y+3.0x2 +4X3 +5X4 <= 124");
        constraints.add(" y + 3x2 +3X4 +6X5 <= 854");

        LP lp = new LP(constraints);
        SolutionType solution_type=lp.resolve();

        if(solution_type==SolutionType.OPTIMUM) {
            Solution soluzione=lp.getSolution();
            for(Variable var:soluzione.getVariables()) {
                SscLogger.log("Variable name :"+var.getName() + " value :"+var.getValue());
            }
            hasil = "Value:"+soluzione.getOptimumValue();
        }
    }
```